# Open Link in HTML with JSOUP

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have a table in a HTML page in which I have to iterate through to open the links into a next page where all the information is. In this page I extract any data I need and return to my basic page.

How do I change pages with the framework `JSoup` in Java? Is it actually possible?

Comment: do you have any examples of what you've tried that we can look at?

Comment: not really. I hope I can explain it. On a website there is a table. In this table are many links. I have to iterate through all of these (means: open them, and save the information somewhere, go back and open the next link).

the information which I want is not on one site but on more than one. this is the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is legal to post the link of the internetsite from which I want the data.

Comment: What is stopping you do it, Its fine with JSOUP to do that just use jsoup.connect whenever you are finding any weblink. If there is no link just come out from while loop.

Comment: Yes, It seems can be possible. First read the links from the table using jsoup and have it in list. Iterate each link from the list to read page info using jsoup and do what ever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [JSoup Cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation), they have an example of getting all the links inside of an HTML element. Iterate the Elements from this example and do a `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(<url from Elements>).get();`. You can then do `String htmlFromLink = doc.toString();` and get the HTML from the link.